# Base64 encode a form with Ninja Forms for Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, ninja-forms

How could I encode a form using Ninja Forms for Wordpress so that is submitted to the server and the server doesn't block it.
The server actually detect URL in the submitted fields and blocks the form.

I took a look at:
http://developer.ninjaforms.com/codex/submission-processing-hooks/

and tried this:

```
add_filter( 'ninja_forms_submit_data', 'my_ninja_forms_submit_data' );
function my_ninja_forms_submit_data( $form_data ) {

  foreach( $form_data[ 'fields' ] as $field ) { // Field settigns, including the field key and value.
   $field = base64_encode($field);
  }

  return $form_data;
}
```

Is it the right way to do it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

```
add_filter( 'ninja_forms_submit_data', 'my_ninja_forms_submit_data', 10, 1 );

    function my_ninja_forms_submit_data( $form_data ) {

      $FormValue = array();
       foreach ($form_data['fields'] as $key => $field) {
            $form_data[$field['key']] = $field['value'];
            $FormValue[$key]['id']  = $field['id'];
            $FormValue[$key]['value']  = base64_encode($field['value']);
        }

      $form_data['fields'] = $FormValue;
      return $form_data;
    }
```

[image]

Comment: I got 'TypeError: Cannot read property 'fields' of undefined'

Comment: Ok got it! Your answer was right. I'll now search to decode value in the WP dashboard